# how can i add a readed file to an array and check each word is unique with nodejs?

Tags: node.js

Like I said in the title: how can I add a read file to an array and check each word is unique with Node.js? it's returning undefined at the moment

here is the code that manage to get the file. example:

```
const fs = require("fs");

const Negative = fs.readFile("Negative_Processed.txt", "utf-8", (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return
    }
    console.log(data.toString().replace(/\r\n/g, '\n').split(' '));
})
```

[Text file](https://github.com/FurkanGozukara/Sentiment-Analysis/blob/master/Turkish_Product_Reviews_by_Gozukara_and_Ozel_2016/Entire_Dataset/Negative_Processed.txt)

Comment: Can you add an example of how your data is?

Comment: yeah edited and added to the main question.

Comment: Take a look on the [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) data structure, which lets you store unique values of any type

Answer (score 0):

My place right now has GitHub blocked (wow) so I'll be guessing what the data looks like.

```js
const fs = require("fs");

const Negative = fs.readFile("Negative_Processed.txt", "utf-8", (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return
    }
    let data_arr = data.toString().replace(/\r\n/g, '\n').split(' '));
    let data_set = new Set(data_arr);
    return Array.from(data_set) === data_arr;
});

console.log(Negative());
```